# Taking rewards being far from baker HW wallet

Tags: baking, ledger, payment

I have my baking node with HW wallet hosted in a secure place far from my place. Today when I have to send rewards to my delegation addresses I have to go to the place and transfer them to the payment account so I can process payments.

I'd like to avoid going to the hosting place and also avoid having a copy of my HW device. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can pair hardware wallets by importing the 24 word seed phrase from one to another. They will then create the same addresses given the same inputs (signing curve, derivation path).

Once paired, you can leave your baking HW wallet where it is and transfer from the paired HW wallet.

Comment: Yes, I know this is an option that's the reason that I said avoid having a copy of my HW device. I wonder if a kind of a smart contract can help me.

Comment: Just re-read that part of your post - "avoid having a copy" :)